# Unlimited energy storage using relativistic flywheel?

Tags: general-relativity, energy-storage

Theoretically, is it possible to store huge amount of energy using a flywheel that spins at speeds that approach light speed? Can the amount of energy be higher than the mass equivalence of the wheel?

Comment: Related: ["Blitzar"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blitzar), Wikipedia.

Comment: Not unlimited, as at a certain point this hypothetical indestructible flywheel would become a black hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, it would be possible to accelerate any mass, even spin a flywheel, to near light speed. As mass increases with speed, relativistic mass could be many times the rest mass. In practice, however, with any material available today, a flywheel would tear itself to pieces long before reaching relativistic speeds.

Comment: Even if you find some magical material which won't break, you have to find a way round the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_paradox.

Comment: @alephzero then your theoretical magic material would have to have elastic properties